# How to serve php requests through a single persistent php-cgi instance?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cgi

How to set up PHP Version 5.2.17 on Apache/2 to serve php requests through a single persistent php-cgi instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword is fastcgi. For php you can run php-fpm.

There are a lot of guides about it, here is one of them: http://voidweb.com/2010/07/the-perfect-lamp-stack-apache2-fastcgi-php-fpm-apc/